# Some typos in my formulas in my thesis

Tags: thesis, errors-erratum

I found some typos (or errors) in my thesis, one formula, the label of one figure, and one citation. My thesis is done. What should I do? I know some students faked data and their degree were revoked. I did not fake data, but **I am not sure how serious these typos are.**

**UPDATE**

I cited and used 5-6 statements from an online report A and changed a little of them. They looks similar. But citation is wrong. I cited B in reference. What should I do? Is it Plagiarism?

Comment: Define "done". Is it signed and submitted to your university already? Have you defended it?

Comment: Yes. Already submitted to my university.

Comment: Have you checked (presumably online) to see if your university has a policy on errata for theses?

Comment: I did not find any such kind of  policies on my university website.

Comment: I read this post, but still have no idea what to do.

Comment: What did your advisor say when you showed them?

Comment: At least three persons reviewed my thesis. They did not find these problems. Neither did I.

Comment: You get your degree revoked for *academic misconduct*. Having typos in formulas and text is not misconduct. It is at worst carelessness; in reality, everyone make mistakes of some kind or other. You will just have to live with it.

Answer (score 2):

Now that you have discovered the issues, you need to get to the bottom of whether they matter. If they typos make the conclusions wrong, you have a more serious issue than if they don't change the overall results.

It doesn't seem like a figure caption is likely to matter (unless it implies the exact opposite of the correct caption, like "Death Rate" instead of "Survival Rate").

An equation typo is unlikely to matter unless it invalidates a proof or gives the wrong values in the final form of an expression. You ought to be able to determine this now.

The citation mistake is annoying because a stickler could accuse you of plagiarism. I think that's unlikely, but it's probably worth fixing if you can.

My recommendation would be to show these three errors to your advisor (assuming your relationship is good) and ask for their *advice*. Helping out with these kinds of issues is their job. Also, they can probably help you navigate/find your university's policy for dealing with thesis errata. Given that pretty much everyone makes mistakes, I'd expect there to be some sort of mechanism for correcting inconsequential mistakes.

If the errors are more important or change the results of your work, you're really going to need your advisor's help. I think talking to them and working through the consequences together are your best bet.

Comment: (1) As for the citation, I would like to cite paper A of person X, but I cited paper B from the same person. Because I need to cite his algorithms. (2) As for the equation, it is one variable used in my simulation. It will confuse readers. (3) as for the figure caption, the figure is to compare two algorithms. what we care about is the gap between them, but now I added wrong descriptions. But the gap is there.

Comment: These sound pretty minor to me. I still suggest you discuss them with your advisor and try to get them fixed. Definitely fix them in any papers that come from your thesis.

Comment: In my published conference paper, there is a equation typo. It does not have the citation and figure caption issues. But I will double check. after that, I will try to contact university and conference organizers.

Comment: @codedog, of course I meant fixing them in any papers you publish related to your thesis from here on out. You may or may not be able to get the already published conference paper modified by the organizers.